# "View data" is to "observance" as "control data" is to what?

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns, analogy

To view data is practising observance, to control data is practising...?

I'm not looking for the antonym of *observance*, I just don't know the "looking:observance::doing:?" word.

Comment: I think we need some more context on this one. What type of data? What type of "control"?

Comment: To the contrary, viewing data is practicing **observation**, not observance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd say "to control data is practising: manipulation"

Comment: *Manipulating data* has a connotation of doing so to serve your own ends. That may or may not be the intended meaning.

Comment: In this sense I disagree.  While "manipulation" in general has a Machiavellian overtone, in the strict sense of computer data, it's merely the corollary to "observe/view".  If you take even one step away from the raw data itself, as in "manipulating a *report* of computer data", then the evil connotation returns.  But at the level of setting or reading bits/bytes, "manipulation" is merely the act of setting bits as opposed to reading them.

Answer (score 1):

The question is so unconstrained a thousand words might work.  A few to consider: *[maintenance](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/maintenance)*, “Actions performed to keep some ... system functioning or in service”; *[editing](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/editing#Noun)*, “an act or instance of something being edited”; *[husbandry](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/husbandry#Noun)* , “The prudent management or conservation of resources”; and also *management* and *conservation*.

Comment: Quite. *Control* (as a noun) would fulfil the criteria, too. The question is borderline Not Constructive.